# How do you redirect a user even before the page loads using IIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, iis-7, authorization

I have three user groups (A, B and C) classified based on some **User Role**. I've built a standalone Angular Application that connects to a backend WebApi Server to fetch data.

User Group A is allowed access only to a particular set of pages while User Group B is allowed access to another set of pages. I need a server level redirect strategy that doesn't even serve the pages to unauthorized users. The server I'm using is IIS 6.2.

The method I'm using right now involves checking cookie value(in JavaScript) for **User Role** and then redirecting the user back to login in case he/she is unauthorized for the page he's attempting to get.

The problem I'm facing is if the page loads slowly(JavaScript executes slowly), the user will still be able to see the areas that are unauthorized for(for a few seconds) him. How do I ensure at a server level (instead of JavaScript Level) that an unauthorized user is never allowed to even see the webpage?

Comment: You need to handle the redirect and access check on your server and not with client side JS.

Comment: I would need the User Role in order to verify if the user is authorized?
How would I get the user-role on my server to verify before serving the page?